# Facebook Login without JSSDK, how to get token if already authorized previously

Tags: vb.net, facebook, .net-4.5

So I am updating an older desktop app (written in VB, .net 4.0) with facebook integration and followed the guide found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/), and have been able to successfully get a token (by parsing the uri of the embedded webview if it contains "token="). Now my problem is if I try to login with a facebook account that has already approved the app in a prior session, the webview just gets redirected to https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html without any token information.

Do I HAVE to log all of the tokens I generate manually (ie on successful token generation, I can call their profile info, use their FB ID as key and save the token)? Even if I do, since the email and password is input directly into the facebook login window, how do I check if the user already has a token?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The access token can change any time, you need to get it everytime. After getting the token, I immediately get the user information https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=??? and use that ID to find their database information.

I couldn't quickly find facebook information but on google's oauth information it says "The access token is also associated with a limited scope that define the kind of data the your client application has access to (for example "Manage your tasks"). An important goal for OAuth 2.0 is to provide secure and convenient access to the protected data, while minimizing the potential impact if an access token is stolen."

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2

Comment: Yeah I was planning to use /me to get their id the first time. But my problem is when they login for the second time++. I have virtually nothing to identify them with (unless I mess with the webview's document before they submit somehow?), hence I cannot lookup the token  I generated previously

Comment: @Prinzovdarkness When they login a second time, get their new token and immidiatly get their ID with /me

Comment: thanks for the response. However that is my problem. In case I wasn't clear: If they login a second time, and they already granted permissions to the app, the URL in the webview DOES NOT have the access token attached. It simply "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" whereas it would have the token as part of the URL if it was their first time approving it

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I finally figured it out myself. My mistake was apparently requesting the **access_token** directly (ie https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=token...) to try and save time.

I fixed it by making a request for a '**code**' instead (ie https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code), which I then use to make a second request to retrieve an access token as documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/, "Exchanging code for an access token" section a bit lower on the page.

Hope this helps someone in the future, this was very frustrating on my part.

Regards,
Prince